# What's $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)$ or $\mathbb{E}(X / (Y+1))$?

Tags: probability, expectation

What's $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)$ or $\mathbb{E}(X / (Y+1))$?

For $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)$ I think I could simply list all the possible values of $|X-Y|$ and then (assuming they all have the same probability) just calculate

$\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)=P_{|X-Y|} \cdot (sum + of + all + possible + values + of + |X-Y|)$

But what about the second one? I think I could (assuming $X,Y$ id) split

$\mathbb{E}(X / (Y+1))=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{Y+1})$,

but what's $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{Y+1})$?

Comment: I dont get it. How can we add 1 to a set?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you work in a discrete setting. The definition for $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is:

$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum{x \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=x)}
$$

In your case:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\dfrac{X}{Y+1}) = \sum{\dfrac{x}{y+1} \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y)}
$$

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent means: $\mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y) = \mathbb{P}(X=x)\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$

Comment: Could you clarify how to infer $\mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y)$ if I'm not given it, but only know about $P_X$ and $P_Y$? Also why is the probability function that for that expected value?